# Creating a matrix in a Javascript Class

Tags: javascript

I am creating a singleton class that has text, numbers, arrays, and a matrix.

How do I create the matrix prototype? I have the following code:

```
var thisClass = new function ()
{
    this.apple = '';
    this.eaten = 0;
    this.anArray = []
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want the matrix to have it's own prototype? Usually, matrices are represented by simple 1D arrays of length rows * columns.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have native matrices. You'll need to roll out your own matrix class.

Comment: Okay.i will do that then

Comment: Depending on your use case, it may be worthwhile using an existing solution such as [gl-matrix](https://github.com/toji/gl-matrix) or [math.js](http://mathjs.org/docs/datatypes/matrices.html)

Comment: what is the specification of your matrix? does it have to have any special methods?

Comment: It is just for storing a grid data so theData[0][0] = 'first grid box' etc. thanks